# Send variable from PHP to JQUERY to other PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an image and after clicking this image I take this game id by JQuery code and then a new PHP tap opens this PHP take should display this image id
Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(".selected").click(function(){
    $.post("bookinfo.php", { id: $(this).attr('id') }, function (response) {
                   alert(response);
               });
});
```

and here is the PHP code

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

?>

and here is the error that i get
**Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\bookinfo.php on line 2**
I have tried AJax request and get but the same error happens..
I have been trying for this error for about 2 hours so please help me!

Comment: I don't see any code that opens a new tab, just that you're trying to send data directly to the server. Also, always check if user provided variables are present at script execution; like such: `$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : false`. Now you can check if `$id == false`. Also, this will resolve your undefined index error.

Comment: its just an html code i used <a href="bookinfo.php" target="_blank"> BOOK IMG </a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**Edited:**

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.selected',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        window.location.replace("bookinfo.php?id=" + id);
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
}
?>
```

Comment: I can see the id that i want in an alert only but i cant see it in the other php page which i wrote in it your code. its empty it never send the id to the other page

Comment: That's AJAX! Do you want it to redirect to a different page?

Comment: i want the ID value to be shown in another php page

Comment: You can do that using superglobal `$_GET` and `window.location.replace()` function. I have updated the above code snippet.

Comment: Happy to hear. Please upvote and accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

in your php you have to return a json to get it from AJAX. just try changing your php code like this.

```html
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
 $data = array($_POST['id']);
 echo  json_encode($data);
}
```